# Partial specialization in a derived class (plus curious recurrent pattern)

Tags: c++, templates

I want to derive from a template base class using the curious recurrent pattern:

```
template<typename A, typename B>
struct base
{
    typedef A type;
};

template<typename B>
struct derived : public base<derived, B>
{
   // Own attributes.
};
```

But the compiler (g++ 4.7.2) tells me the arguments (derived/A) doesn't match.

How should I do it?

Comment: You should add the complete error message an the code inside the derived class

Comment: http://ideone.com/TAwac8

Comment: My "complete error message" is in spanish. For this reason I haven't put the error message here. And the code is just as you see, with a empty main.

Comment: @Peregring-lk: `LANG=C make`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting the error becaused `derived` is a *class template*, and you're leaving out its template parameters.  You need to specify the template parameters for `derived`:

```
template<typename B>
struct derived : public base<derived<B>, B>
{
   // Own attributes.
};
```

Comment: That's right. `derived` is equivalent to `derived<B>` inside the template definition, but not in its base class specification.